# How to create unique link that will work with function

Tags: python, django

I have project with rooms, where one user can create rooms and others can join, but i want to create private rooms which you can join only by unique link that will receive and send you a creator of this room.How i can implement that?

Comment: Checkout [How to make unique short URL with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497504/how-to-make-unique-short-url-with-python), especially the later suggestions.

Comment: You can use [secrets.token_urlsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe) to generate a strong unique url

Comment: Give each room a unique identifier and then use something like that                       
[link](http://example.com/join?roomid=Dxjsaw) and then connect the user by the special ID of the room.