# Generating strings from regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I think it can be done by generating strings using brute force and then try to match them to the supplied regex and printing if match.

But is there a better way to do this?

Regex are used to test if a string matches a pattern.
I am aware of that. I thought it would be interesting to do it the way around.

Comment: [Higher Order Perl has a section discussing this problem](http://books.google.com/books?id=4_q8JJWNaTsC&lpg=PA273&ots=tkMse5dbQy&dq=higher%20order%20perl%20generate%20strings%20from%20regex&pg=PA272#v=onepage&q=higher%20order%20perl%20generate%20strings%20from%20regex&f=false). It's worth reading for other reasons, too.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve, what's the question?

Comment: There's no built-in way to generate matching strings from a regular expression in JavaScript.  You'd have to write code to do it, and there are definitely better ways to do it than to generate random strings and see whether they match. It's a non-trivial problem however.

Comment: I wish to generate strings that match a regex.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  Do you want a method that, given a RegExp, will return x random Strings that match the pattern?

Comment: But why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Pointy - I am looking for those better methods you mentioned sir.

Comment: @blurd

I wish to generate a string without hard-coding it. And I wan it to follow a pattern. And i wish to use regex.

Comment: Regex is typically used to find strings that match a pattern, not to generate them.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367586/generating-random-text-strings-of-a-given-pattern

Comment: @blurd  I am aware of that. I thought it would be interesting to do it the way around.

Comment: So what type of pattern do you need them to match, what's the regular expression they should match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random string based on a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959850/generate-a-random-string-based-on-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript, there's [Randexp](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js) which generates random strings that match a given regex.

[Releases for browser](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases)

Comment: Randexp generates only one random string from a regex. To generate every possible match, you can use [genexp.js](https://github.com/alixaxel/genex.js) instead.

Answer (score 5):

##### Use [randexp.js](http://fent.github.io/randexp.js/) to generate random strings from a regular expression:

```js
console.log(new RandExp(/^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}$/).gen());
console.log(new RandExp(/^[0-9]{4}$/).gen());
console.log(new RandExp(/^[0-9,A-Z]{4}$/).gen());
console.log(new RandExp(/^([A-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([A-Z]){1}$/).gen());
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases/download/v0.4.3/randexp.min.js"></script>
```