# Generate large random text files with python and NumPy

Tags: python, string, file, numpy, random

For testing data, I am in need of quickly creating large files of random text. I have one solution, [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367586/generating-random-text-strings-of-a-given-pattern) and given below:

```
import random
import string

n = 1024 ** 2  # 1 Mb of text
chars = ''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for i in range(n)])

with open('textfile.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(chars)
```

My problem is that this takes 653 ms to perform, way too much for my uses.

Is there a faster way to quickly generate text files with random text?

Comment: I'm curious, what is the use case here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random text strings of a given pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367586/generating-random-text-strings-of-a-given-pattern)

Comment: You can put random.choice(string.letters) for i in range(n) into generator and use yield to make it faster

Comment: Use some thing like faker library for python

Comment: The duplicate suggests exactly my example, and as mentioned it is too slow. The use case would be to generate random text for automated testing (the main goal is to do regression testing of performance on a parser).

Comment: @JonasAdler Do you use numpy?

Comment: Numpy is totally a valid approach

Comment: @JonasAdler I timed an approach with numpy that gets this down to 370ms. Is that still too slow?

Comment: @dmitryro I cannot pass a generator to `f.write`, and using a generator inside `''.join()` gives no performance increase. But I do agree it improves the code.

Comment: If 370ms with numpy is the best we got, I'll have to make do. But I was hoping for an order of magnitude.

Comment: You're asking Python to do something fast, which is not what Python does. Pick a different language, like C.

Comment: But python does lots of things fast, I don't see why I should be stuck with simple loops. At the very least this should be vectorizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a numpy array of letters:

```
In [662]: letters = np.array(list(chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(26))); letters
Out[662]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
       'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Use `np.random.choice` to generate random indices b/w 0 and 26, and index `letters` to generate random text:

```
np.random.choice(letters, n)
```

#### Timings:

```
In [664]: n = 1024 ** 2

In [701]: %timeit np.random.choice(letters, n)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.1 ms per loop
```

Alternatively,

```
In [705]: %timeit np.random.choice(np.fromstring(letters, dtype='<U1'), n)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: I am able to modify this somewhat and get an order of magnitude better performance: `np.random.choice(np.fromstring(string.letters, dtype='S1'), n)`, total time `17 ms`. Could you update the answer to that and I'll accept that answer?

Comment: @JonasAdler That gives you a list of chars, right? You'll want to join them together.

Comment: It seems `f.write` accepts char arrays. The result looks alright and writing is basically instant.

Comment: @JonasAdler I got you a bit faster, if you don't mind the fact they're not binary strings.

Comment: @JonasAdler Glad to help :)